# How i delete not my message but message that sent the bot to me?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

```
client.on('message', async (message) => {
    if (message.author.bot) return;
    if (message.content.startsWith('-queue open ')) {
    message.content = message.content.replace('-queue open ', '')
    message.channel.send(`Queue has been created with number of members: ${message.content}`).then(m => setTimeout(() => {
        message.delete()
    }, 2000))
}
});
```

How i can use function message.delete() to it delete **message that bot** send as reply to my message?

Answer (score 0):

I think you already got the answer, but you are using the wrong message object. In your code `message` is the message from the user. When you call `message.channel.send` is [returns a Promise](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/master/class/TextChannel?scrollTo=send) which contains the new sent message. You assign this new message to the parameter `m`. So the solution should be `m.delete()` and not `message.delete()`.

```
client.on('message', async (message) => {
   if (message.author.bot) return;
   if (message.content.startsWith('-queue open ')) {
      message.content = message.content.replace('-queue open ', '')
      message.channel.send(`Queue has been created with number of members: ${message.content}`)
     .then(m => setTimeout(() => { m.delete() }, 2000))
   }
 });
```